# adding a viewControllers view to another viewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am completely new to iPhone development. I have two ViewControllers

1. ViewControllerA
2. ViewControllerB

ViewControllerA is the first one and launches with the app.

I have another ViewControllerB now I want to add view of ViewControllerB as subview to ViewControllerA's view when application launches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
ViewControllerB *vcb = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:vcb.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

A belated answer. I just wrote some words about my solution for this question. It can be found here:
http://blog.nguyenthanhnhon.info/2014/04/how-to-add-viewcontrollernavigationcont.html

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the object of VC globally .. otherwise you face some issues.

@interface ViewControllerA ()

{

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerBObj;
```

}

-(void) viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

viewControllerBObj = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];


[self.view addSubview:viewControllerBObj.view];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this

in "viewDidLoad" method of "ViewController1"

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
[self addChildViewController: vc2];
[self.view addSubview: vc2.view];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the view of a view controller by using it's `view` property. If you have pointers to two view controllers `myControllerA` and `myControllerB` then you can add B's view to A's view by using this.

```
[myControllerA.view addSubview:myControllerB.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[self.view addSubView:ViewControllerB.view]` in the `viewDidLoad()` of ViewControllerA.